# Calculating Average of Previous Three Months' Total Invoice in Oracle Analytics Cloud

Tags: oracle

I'm working on a project in Oracle Analytics Cloud and need assistance with calculating the average of the previous three months' "Monthly total invoice" values for each "Outlet Code." I have a dataset that includes fields like "Branch ID," "Branch Name," "Outlet Code," "Outlet Name," "Outlet Channel," "Month," "Year," and "Monthly total invoice."

Here's the calculation I'm aiming to achieve:

For each month after the first three months (Month 4 onwards), I want to calculate the average of the "Monthly total invoice" values for the previous three months (Month 1, Month 2, and Month 3).
However, I want to exclude months with missing or zero "Monthly total invoice" values from the calculation. For example, if Month 3 only has data for Month 2 and Month 1, the average should be calculated based on those two months' values only.
I've explored using the Avg function and the CASE statement in Oracle Analytics Cloud, but I'm encountering syntax errors and limitations related to the IGNORE NULLS clause and other features.

Data Sample:

Branch ID   Branch Name Outlet Code Outlet Name Outlet Channel  Month   Year    Monthly total invoice
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
Desired Output:
I'd like to create a new field called "AMS" that holds the calculated average values as described above. The solution should work within the capabilities of Oracle Analytics Cloud's functions.

Request:
I'm seeking assistance in formulating a valid SQL query or a sequence of functions in Oracle Analytics Cloud that can achieve the required calculation. If anyone has experience working with Oracle Analytics Cloud and can provide insights or sample code to help me solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide sample input data and desired results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask